# I want to make each counter work independently but, they just continue from where the last counter stopped

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

```
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(`.plus`);
let minus = document.querySelectorAll(`.minus`);
const amount = document.querySelectorAll(`.amount`);

let counter;
let newCounter;
for (i = 0; i < plus.length; i++) {
    counter = 0;
    newCounter = 0;

    minus[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[3].textContent);
        if (counter === 0) {
            e.target.parentElement.childNodes[3].textContent = 0;
        }   else {
            e.target.parentElement.childNodes[3].textContent = counter-= 1;
        }
    })

    plus[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.parentElement.childNodes[3].textContent = counter+= 1;
    })
}


HTML
<div class="container">
    <p class="price">N4 000 - N8 500</p>
    <article class="amountSection">
        <button class="amountBtn minus" id="S08">-</
button>
        <p class="amount">0</p>
        <button class="amountBtn plus">+</button>
</div>
```

So, from the code above I tried looping through the code to avoid writing the same thing for each counter but, I just can't get them to work independently. Please help, I am new to Javascript. Thank you.`

Comment: Make all your variables local to the loop by declaring them with `let`. Otherwise they're global variables, and all the buttons use the same variable.